# Access to an hash table element in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, hashtable

I would like access to a hash table element created by a function without creating an intermediate variable.

Here's code to explain what I want to do:

```
Function bla($aParameter) {
    $ret = @{}
    for($i in XX) {
        $ret.Add([int]$i, [string]$value)
    }
    $ret
}

$myVar = ""
$myVar += (bla $aParameter).1 + ","
```

I tried `$myVar += ((bla $aParameter).1) + ","` without much success.

Comment: FWIW your example works in PowerShell v3 (except swap in a `foreach` for your `for` statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the result to string like this:

```
$myVar += [string]((bla $aParameter).1) + ","
```

Which is weird since I already cast the value of my HashTable to `[string]`.